# Filter is applied after DISTINCT ON

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.5, query-performance

There's a script at the end that will fully create the schema and populate it with sample data.

#### Schema

Consider these two tables:

Table of polygons:

```
CREATE TABLE my_polygon (
    my_polygon_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    common_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    value1 NUMERIC NOT NULL,
    value2 NUMERIC NOT NULL,
    value3 NUMERIC NOT NULL,
    geom GEOMETRY(Polygon) NOT NULL
)
;

CREATE INDEX ON my_polygon (common_id);
CREATE INDEX ON my_polygon USING GIST (common_id, geom);
```

Table of points contained inside polygons:

```
CREATE TABLE my_point (
    my_point_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    common_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    pointvalue NUMERIC NOT NULL,
    geom GEOMETRY(Point) NOT NULL
);

CREATE INDEX ON my_point (common_id);
CREATE INDEX ON my_point USING GIST (common_id, geom);
```

The fact that I'm using geometries isn't strictly related to the issue here; however, I think this makes the motives for what I'm attempting to do much clearer.

#### Problem query

The problem is that there are *very* tiny, insignificant overlaps between the polygons. (Trying to clean them is really not an option. The overlaps come from some kind of floating point error in generating them, as near as I can figure.) But some points can fall inside these tiny overlaps, resulting in two rows when I `JOIN` them based on containment. But really, each point should only be associated with a single polygon. When one does fall within two of them, it doesn't really matter which one it ends up associated with, so it's fine to make the query just pick one, like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (my_point.my_point_id)
    my_polygon.*,
    my_point.my_point_id,
    my_point.pointvalue,
    my_point.geom AS pointgeom
FROM my_polygon
JOIN my_point ON my_point.common_id = my_polygon.common_id AND ST_Contains(my_polygon.geom, my_point.geom)
WHERE my_polygon.common_id = 1
ORDER BY my_point.my_point_id, my_polygon.my_polygon_id
```

As in the above query, I normally want to `SELECT` based on the `common_id`. This query performs fine. It's query plan looks like this:

[image: Good query plan]

However, this is logic I need in a number of different queries, so I wanted to put it in a view. The result is that, as far as the query planner is concerned, the query looks like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (my_point.my_point_id)
        my_polygon.*,
        my_point.my_point_id,
        my_point.pointvalue,
        my_point.geom AS pointgeom
    FROM my_polygon
    JOIN my_point ON my_point.common_id = my_polygon.common_id AND ST_Contains(my_polygon.geom, my_point.geom)
    ORDER BY my_point.my_point_id, my_polygon.my_polygon_id
) point_with_polygon
WHERE common_id = 1
```

The result is that now PostgreSQL filters by `common_id` *after* performing the `DISTINCT ON`, which means that it has to `JOIN` the entirety of both tables. Here's it's query plan:

[image: Bad query plan]

How can I allow PostgreSQL to push the filter down into an early part of the query and still put the general query in a view?

I'm stuck on PG 9.3 right now, but upgrading to 9.5 may be an option.

#### Schema and sample data script

Requires PostGIS. (That's why there's no SQL Fiddle.)

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS postgis;
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS btree_gist;

-- DROP FUNCTION ST_GeneratePoints(geometry, numeric);
DO $doblock$
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM pg_proc WHERE UPPER(proname) = UPPER('ST_GeneratePoints')) THEN
        -- Create naive ST_GeneratePoints if version of PostGIS is not new enough
        CREATE FUNCTION ST_GeneratePoints(g geometry, npoints numeric)
            RETURNS geometry
            VOLATILE
            RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT
            LANGUAGE plpgsql
            AS $$
            DECLARE
                num_to_generate INTEGER := npoints::INTEGER;
                adjustment CONSTANT FLOAT := 0.00000000001;
                x_min FLOAT := ST_XMin(g) + adjustment;
                x_max FLOAT := ST_XMax(g) - adjustment;
                y_min FLOAT := ST_YMin(g) + adjustment;
                y_max FLOAT := ST_YMax(g) - adjustment;
                temp_result GEOMETRY[];
                result_array GEOMETRY[] := ARRAY[]::GEOMETRY[];
            BEGIN
                IF ST_IsEmpty(g) THEN
                    RAISE EXCEPTION 'Cannot generate points inside an empty geometry';
                END IF;

                IF ST_Dimension(g) < 2 THEN
                    RAISE EXCEPTION 'Only polygons supported';
                END IF;

                -- Reduce number of loops to reduce slow array_cat calls
                WHILE num_to_generate > 0 LOOP
                    SELECT ARRAY_AGG(contained.point) INTO temp_result
                    FROM (
                        SELECT point
                        FROM (
                            SELECT ST_MakePoint(
                                x_min + random() * (x_max - x_min),
                                y_min + random() * (y_max - y_min)
                            ) point
                            -- Generate extras to reduce number of loops
                            --
                            -- Each point has a probability of  ST_Area(g) / ST_Area(ST_Envelope(g))  to fall within the polygon.
                            -- So on average, we expect ST_Area(g) / ST_Area(ST_Envelope(g)) of the points generated to fall within.
                            -- Generating  ST_Area(ST_Envelope(g)) / ST_Area(g) * num_to_generate  points means that on average, we'll
                            -- get
                            --
                            --     ST_Area(g) / ST_Area(ST_Envelope(g)) * ST_Area(ST_Envelope(g)) / ST_Area(g) * num_to_generate
                            --      = num_to_generate
                            --
                            -- points within the polygon. (Notice the numerators and denominators cancel out.) This means we'll 
                            -- only run one loop about half the time without generating an excessive number of points.
                            --
                            -- Generate at least 20 to avoid a lot of loops for small numbers, though.
                            FROM generate_series(1, GREATEST(20, CEIL(ST_Area(ST_Envelope(g)) / ST_Area(g) * num_to_generate)::INTEGER))
                        ) candidate
                        WHERE ST_Contains(g, candidate.point)
                        -- Filter out extras if we have too many matches
                        LIMIT num_to_generate
                    ) contained
                    ;
                    IF ARRAY_LENGTH(temp_result, 1) > 0 THEN
                        result_array := array_cat(result_array, temp_result);
                        num_to_generate := npoints - COALESCE(ARRAY_LENGTH(result_array, 1), 0);
                    END IF;
                END LOOP;
                RETURN (SELECT ST_Union(point) FROM UNNEST(result_array) result (point));
            END;
            $$;
        RAISE NOTICE 'Created ST_GeneratePoints';
    ELSE
        RAISE NOTICE 'ST_GeneratePoints exists';
    END IF;
END
$doblock$
;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_polygon;

CREATE TABLE my_polygon (
    my_polygon_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    common_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    value1 NUMERIC NOT NULL,
    value2 NUMERIC NOT NULL,
    value3 NUMERIC NOT NULL,
    geom GEOMETRY(Polygon) NOT NULL
)
;

CREATE INDEX ON my_polygon (common_id);
CREATE INDEX ON my_polygon USING GIST (common_id, geom);


WITH common AS (
    SELECT
        common_id,
        random() * 5000 AS common_x_translate,
        random() * 5000 AS common_y_translate
    FROM (
        SELECT TRUNC(random() * 1000) + 1 AS common_id
        FROM generate_series(1, 100)
        UNION 
        SELECT 1
    ) a
),
geom_set_with_small_overlaps AS (
    SELECT
        ST_MakeEnvelope(
            x.translate, 
            y.translate, 
            x.translate + 1.1, 
            y.translate + 1.1
        ) AS geom
    FROM
        generate_series(0, 9) x (translate),
        generate_series(0, 9) y (translate)
)
INSERT INTO my_polygon (common_id, value1, value2, value3, geom)
SELECT
    common_id,
    random() * 100,
    random() * 100,
    random() * 100,
    ST_Translate(geom, common_x_translate, common_y_translate)
FROM common, geom_set_with_small_overlaps
;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_point;

CREATE TABLE my_point (
    my_point_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    common_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    pointvalue NUMERIC NOT NULL,
    geom GEOMETRY(Point) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_point (common_id, pointvalue, geom)
SELECT
    common_id,
    random() * 100,
    (ST_Dump(ST_GeneratePoints(extent, FLOOR(5000 + random() * 15000)::NUMERIC))).geom
FROM (
    SELECT
        common_id,
        -- Small negative buffer prevents lying on the outer edge
        ST_Buffer(ST_Extent(geom), - 0.0001) AS extent
    FROM my_polygon
    GROUP BY common_id
) common
UNION ALL
SELECT
    common_id,
    random() * 100,
    (ST_Dump(ST_GeneratePoints(intersection, TRUNC(random() * 5)::NUMERIC))).geom
FROM (
    SELECT
        p1.common_id,
        p1.my_polygon_id AS id1,
        p2.my_polygon_id AS id2,
        ST_Intersection(p1.geom, p2.geom) AS intersection
    FROM my_polygon p1
    JOIN my_polygon p2 ON (
        p1.my_polygon_id < p2.my_polygon_id AND
        p1.common_id = p2.common_id AND
        ST_Intersects(p1.geom, p2.geom)
    )
) a
;

CREATE INDEX ON my_point (common_id);
CREATE INDEX ON my_point USING GIST (common_id, geom);
```

You probably want to `VACUUM ANALYZE` after that.

#### Query plans as text

`WHERE` clause inside (good performance):

```
Unique  (cost=1195.74..1207.74 rows=2400 width=216)
  ->  Sort  (cost=1195.74..1201.74 rows=2400 width=216)
        Sort Key: my_point.my_point_id, my_polygon.my_polygon_id
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=5.34..1060.99 rows=2400 width=216)
              ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on my_polygon  (cost=4.93..191.74 rows=100 width=164)
                    Recheck Cond: (common_id = 1)
                    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on my_polygon_common_id_geom_idx  (cost=0.00..4.90 rows=100 width=0)
                          Index Cond: (common_id = 1)
              ->  Index Scan using my_point_common_id_geom_idx on my_point  (cost=0.41..8.68 rows=1 width=52)
                    Index Cond: ((common_id = 1) AND (my_polygon.geom && geom))
                    Filter: _st_contains(my_polygon.geom, geom)
```

`WHERE` clause outside (bad performance):

```
Subquery Scan on a  (cost=209447.85..215842.18 rows=1827 width=212)
  Filter: (a.common_id = 1)
  ->  Unique  (cost=209447.85..211274.80 rows=365390 width=212)
        ->  Sort  (cost=209447.85..210361.33 rows=365390 width=212)
              Sort Key: my_point.my_point_id, my_polygon.my_polygon_id
              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.41..63285.00 rows=365390 width=212)
                    ->  Seq Scan on my_polygon  (cost=0.00..338.00 rows=9800 width=164)
                    ->  Index Scan using my_point_common_id_geom_idx on my_point  (cost=0.41..6.41 rows=1 width=52)
                          Index Cond: ((common_id = my_polygon.common_id) AND (my_polygon.geom && geom))
                          Filter: _st_contains(my_polygon.geom, geom)
```

Comment: It looks like the `WHERE` clause is missing above.  Without it it's hard to tell what's going on.  Also, do you have an `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` output, too?  Are the too queries very different in their execution time?  Otherwise, I don't really understand why someone downvoted - might be a misdirected click.

Comment: When pushing down a filter changes the result, the output essentially becomes a *function* of that filter. Hence, a view cannot be used in your case.

Comment: @dezso You're correct. My apologies. I made some kind of copy/paste error. It's been added. Thank you.

Comment: @AndriyM I disagree with that line of thinking. It would preclude *all* optimizations that involve pushing down a filter into a view, which PG certainly does do in some cases.

Comment: Please post the execution plan as formatted text, the graphical plan hides too many important details

Comment: @dezso I don't have `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` output available, but the performance difference is huge. With the sample script, it takes about 3 times longer. In my real data, it would be an even bigger difference (since I have thousands of `common_id`s to group by, rather than just 100). But I think the problem is pretty obvious just from the query plan: since the filter isn't pushed down, the second query has to join the entirety of both tables. The first query filters one of the tables and then does ` more limited `JOIN`, allowing the DB to process significantly fewer rows in both tables.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Will do, even though I think I've identified the problem already. Is the old multi-row result format or the newer JSON result format preferred?

Comment: I personally prefer the plain text output - JSON just confuses me - but that might just be me

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Done. On second thought, you're right. It's useful to see the huge difference in row estimates.

Comment: Sorry. Had a clean sample and forgot to `VACUUM ANALYZE` first. Corrected.

Comment: @ jpmc26  WRT to changing version of PostgreSQL: I've checked it with both 9.4 and 9.6, and both show the same behaviour. I'd be surprised if 9.5 would behave otherwise. 

I have seen similar situations where the "DISTINCT" makes PostgreSQL not to push the WHERE clause. (If the DISTINCT clause isn't present, you get the same plans in both cases). I don't know why it cannot be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out there's a way to work around this and get PG to optimize correctly: you have to **include `common_id` in the `DISTINCT ON` clause**.

Like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (my_point.my_point_id, my_polygon.common_id)
        my_polygon.*,
        my_point.my_point_id,
        my_point.pointvalue,
        my_point.geom AS pointgeom
    FROM my_polygon
    JOIN my_point ON my_point.common_id = my_polygon.common_id AND ST_Contains(my_polygon.geom, my_point.geom)
    ORDER BY my_point.my_point_id, my_polygon.common_id, my_polygon.my_polygon_id
) point_with_polygon
WHERE common_id = 1
```

This results in the same query plan as including the `WHERE` clause before the `DISTINCT ON`:

```
Unique  (cost=2307.77..2345.55 rows=5038 width=212)
  ->  Sort  (cost=2307.77..2320.36 rows=5038 width=212)
        Sort Key: my_point.my_point_id, my_polygon.my_polygon_id
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=9.36..1479.97 rows=5038 width=212)
              ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on my_polygon  (cost=4.93..190.19 rows=100 width=164)
                    Recheck Cond: (common_id = 1)
                    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on my_polygon_common_id_geom_idx  (cost=0.00..4.90 rows=100 width=0)
                          Index Cond: (common_id = 1)
              ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on my_point  (cost=4.43..12.89 rows=1 width=52)
                    Recheck Cond: ((common_id = 1) AND (my_polygon.geom && geom))
                    Filter: _st_contains(my_polygon.geom, geom)
                    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on my_point_common_id_geom_idx  (cost=0.00..4.43 rows=2 width=0)
                          Index Cond: ((common_id = 1) AND (my_polygon.geom && geom))
```

Including `common_id` is kind of redundant since it's part of the `JOIN` condition anyway, but that fact also means that this won't change the result of the query.

#### Warning: Make sure everything matches up

It's *very* important that you use the `common_id` that's **in the `SELECT` result**. Take this query for example:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (my_point.my_point_id, my_point.common_id)
        my_polygon.*,
        my_point.my_point_id,
        my_point.pointvalue,
        my_point.geom AS pointgeom
    FROM my_polygon
    JOIN my_point ON my_point.common_id = my_polygon.common_id AND ST_Contains(my_polygon.geom, my_point.geom)
    ORDER BY my_point.my_point_id, my_point.common_id, my_polygon.my_polygon_id
) point_with_polygon
WHERE common_id = 1
```

This query uses `my_polygon.common_id` in the `SELECT` clause, but it uses `my_point.common_id` in the `ORDER BY` and `DISTINCT ON` clauses. PG will **not** push the filter down into the subquery in this case.

Comment: ...Unfortunately, this doesn't work if you filter another table that has `common_id` and then `JOIN` it to this query. =/